# MDADM Array Detection Slowing Down Boot - Why?

Tags: gentoo, systemd, mdadm, initramfs

I have an AMD64 Gentoo (running `systemd`) build with a RAID0 root and some other arrays (RAID1 boot, RAID1 home etc..). The boot process is being slowed down quite dramatically as `mdadm` searches the arrays at boot (from the initramfs).

I've tried:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Removing info about metadata etc.. (as suggested elsewhere), and then telling Gentoo's genkernel to pull in the `mdadm.conf` into the initramfs through `genkernel.conf`.

But it's still holding up the boot process. I have an alternate distro (Debian) installed on a separate partition which also runs systemd and which boots much quicker. Any ideas?

Comment: My idea would be to read the initramfs scripts generated by the two systems, and see the differences in there.

Answer (score 0):

What's inside the `mdadm.conf` used by Debian vs Gentoo?.

Specifically, what is used for the `DEVICE` line. If that points to some slow device or is omitted, then mdadm will take a long time to probe.

Eg, on my system, I have a couple of `/dev/sdX` devices that correspond to SD card readers built into my monitors. They are present regardless of any SD cards being inserted, and probing them takes a non-zero amount of time.

You should narrow it down if possible.

The mdadm version may also be worth checking.